# Combine commits (not the last, some older ones)

Tags: git

I have some history like that :

First commit -> 2 -> 3 -> some branches and merges -> ...

I have a linear succession of small commits at the beginning (2 -> 3) that I would like to combine together. I have read about git rebase -i, but I dont know how to apply to commits other than the last ones.

Comment: Be aware that `git rebase` normally removes merges entirely.  Adding `-p` preserves merges (or tries to—it has to actually re-perform the merges so it loses any manual conflict resolution or other Evil Merge action), but behaves badly if you fiddle with other commits.

Answer (score 1):

Rebase will work to merge 2 and 3 but it will mess with all other developers that have `some branches` in their repo when they pull your rebased patches.

So this is not recommended if you are sharing your work with others but if it is ok in your context (you are working alone or you can say to *every developer* to reset their branches to your rebased branch) then just use:

```
git rebase -i FIRST_COMMIT
```

and pick all patches but squash 3.

Comment: Error : could not apply 758fe3d (...)   
I am not sure why but this specific commit seems to cause an error